# Who was the US town Hayden in Arizona named after?

Tags: united-states, names

Is the town [Hayden, AZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayden,_Arizona) named after Charles Hayden?

Charles Hayden was the principal of Stone & Hayden, which owned the Kennecott mines. Hayden AZ was founded in 1911 according to the Wikipedia article. I can't think of any other Hayden that Hayden, AZ would be named after...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the wikipedia article about Charles [Hayden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Hayden_(banker)), he was

> Instrumental in the financing of Arizona copper mines and smelters, the smelting community of Hayden, Arizona was named for him.

This is corroborated by such sources as *The Encylopedia of Arizona*[, page 172](https://books.google.com/books?id=mlcnj7a4XAsC&pg=PA172&lpg=PA172&dq=hayden+stone+company+gila+county&source=bl&ots=R5zCM2pezf&sig=ACfU3U3WcfGYVwUhBh0YGpf6_oe5fSP1aA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwii1bqGmr7yAhUVKVkFHWBbDkIQ6AF6BAgUEAM#v=onepage&q=hayden%20stone%20company%20gila%20county&f=false), local civic booster publications such as [this one](https://www.discovergilacounty.com/post/what-s-in-a-name-how-did-southern-gila-county-town-s-establish-their-name-s) and an entry on Hayden on a [find a gravestone site](https://www.findagrave.com/memorial/42349374/charles-willard-hayden).  (This last gives him a middle name, "Willard", which is not present on his tombstone or in his *New York Times* obituary.)   The "named after" claim is not given in his *NYT* obituary.

Note that the eponymic Charles Hayden (financier, philanthropist, donor of the Hayden Planetarium) is not the same person as [Charles T. Hayden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_T._Hayden), important in Arizona history as a founder of the  city of Tempe and of  Arizona State University.

Comment: Please notice that neither the Wikipedia article on Charles Hayden nor the one on Hayden have any reference to support that claim.

Comment: @Pere Which claim is "that claim"?

Comment: The claim thay Hayden, Arizona was named after Charles Hayden.

Comment: @Pere  You are right.  I have edited in some witnesses, but _they_ cite no sources, and are hence equally suspect.  One suspects that the New York Times obituary for Hayden  (mentioned in his WP entry) has something to say on the topic, too, but if it did it would probably  be equally unsourced.

Comment: Well, a New York Times obituary is far from perfect but it would be a better source than an unreferenced claim in Wikipedia (or in StackExchange), which could just be a guess that seemed reasonable (or even obvious) to the editor who wrote it. In other questions such a guess would add some value, but in this question the OP already made that guess (or is aware of it) and is asking for confirmation. I think your last edition actually answers the question. +1

Comment: Btw, I added your sources to the Wikipedia article.